# How to measure the length of a class with the property display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to measure the elements with a certain class that have display:none in javaScript jQuery?

For example:

```
<div class="x" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="x" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
```

If I do this code below I'll get an alert "3" as there is 3 elements with class="x".

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName('x').length;
alert(n);
```

What would be the proper selector so that my alert show the only 2 classes "x" with display:none?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mixing the class name and [:hidden selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

```
  var list =  $('.x:hidden'); //select all elements with class x and are hidden.
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XLqs6/)**

Here in vanilla JS:

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName('x'); //get the elements with class
var nodeList = []; 
for(var i=0, len = n.length; i<len; i++){ //loop through them
    if(n[i].style.display === "none") nodeList.push(n[i]); //check for display property value and push the element to the list.
}
alert(nodeList.length); //You have the list of elements with desired properties.
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EuGBj/)**

Comment: what would be a similar selector using javascript?

Comment: @enriqg9 You dont have that selector yet because `:hidden` is not a css specification, if it had been css spec then similar selector can be used in `document.querySelectorAll`